# local login from DBA group member (as sysdba) not working

Tags: oracle, centos

good day!

i'm confronted with the following situation

- OS: CentOS 7 x86_64
- user: oracle (member of DBA group, owner of /u01/app (drwxr-sr-x)
- /etc/oratab: orcl12c:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1:Y
- after starting LISTENER manually, Listener reports "The listener supports no services"
- sqlplus sys/*@co7ora12cvm:1521/orcl12c as sysdba returns
  «ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor»
- dbstart starts listener but errors out with ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
- i'm able to start the database through dbca (Configure database options > Next > Next)
- once this is done LISTENER know of the services orcl12c and orcl12cXDB
- once this is done, sqlplus username@orcl12c works fine
- sqlplus as sysdba throws the /? output.
- ping co7ora12cvm works
- tnsping orcl12c times out (TNS-12535)

listener.ora

`LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = co7ora12cvm)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )`

shrept.lst

`(##) function entry points for genclntsh.sh`

network : snaumihi_inithostinfo
network : snaumbg_gmt
network : naedpwd_encrypt
network : naumbsb_bld_singlebyte
network : nlgh
network : nsdhctx_establish
network : nsdhctx_respond
network : nsdhctx_close
network : nsdhctx_inuse
network : snlsmDscFromString
network : snlsmCreate
network : snlsmDestroy
network : snlsmDscToString

sqlnet.ora

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)`

tnsnames.ora

`ORCL12C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = co7ora12cvm)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl12c)
    )
  )`

this is a new install that has never started "normally"

thanks in advance for any suggestion

############# UPDATE user/hosts

as already mentioned i do this as user oracle which is member of the dba team

this is run on vmware and i do the networking with the hosts files

/etc/hosts on co7ora12vm

`127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.178.30<>co7ora12cvm.localdomain co7ora12cvm`

c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (on Windows 7)

`192.168.178.30          co7ora12cvm.localdomain co7ora12cvm`

############# UPDATE sqlnet.ora

thanks for spotting this, indeed, alas it makes no difference

- sqlplus sys/sys@co7ora12cvm:1521/orcl12c as sysdba gives ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor  before  instance is started through dbca; once instance is started it connects
- sqlplus / as sysdba  always gives ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

this happens no matter what sqlnet.ora contains

- SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = ()
- SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
- NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT) such as on my 10g vm where sqplus / as sysdba works

?

Comment: Is `co7ora12cvm` in `/etc/hosts` or DNS? What Unix user are you trying to do this as, and are they in the correct group? Did you install with a pdb/cdb?

Answer (score 3):

You have disabled local OS authentication by setting this:

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)`

Remove the above line from sqlnet.ora, after that, you will be able to log in to the database with:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

Comment: Good bit of detective work :-)

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE_SID was not set =>

`$ export ORACLE_SID=orcl12c
$ sqlplus / as sysdba`

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Oct 17 03:25:16 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1795162112 bytes
Fixed Size                  2925456 bytes
Variable Size             553651312 bytes
Database Buffers         1224736768 bytes
Redo Buffers               13848576 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
$

/home/oracle/.bash_profile

`(#) .bash_profile`

(#) Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
<------>. ~/.bashrc
fi

(#) User specific environment and startup programs

export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=co7ora12cvm
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=orcl12c